# What is the probability of something happening, given 5 things that each have a probability of making that thing happen?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of a cake being eaten if A has a 45% probability of eating the cake, B has a 60% probability, C has a 75% probability, D has a 50% probability, and E has a 55% probability?

I am not sure what method should be used to solve this problem. So far I have looked at Bayes Theorem but I am not sure if this is the way to go.

Comment: Similar question (not saying that it's the same, but if you understand the referenced problem, you should be able to understand your own question): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414920/calculate-the-odds-of-losing-when-there-are-multiple-ways-to-win/3414927#3414927

Comment: Hint: Calculate the probability that no-one eats the cake.

Comment: The wording of the question is unfortunate because it suggests that each person either eats the whole cake or does not eat it at all.

Comment: This depends somewhat on whether it is possible to eat the cake and have it, too.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that each person eats the whole cake or leaves it alone, the answer is           1-0.55x0.4x0.25x0.5x0.45

Comment: Actually, if at most one person eats the cake (because they eat the whole cake if they do), we have six disjoint events "A eats the cake", .... "E eats the cake", "nobody eats the cake", the probabilities of which sum to $0.45+0.60+0.75 + 0.50+0.55+x\gg 1$